# Symfony form label translation errors

Tags: forms, label, translation, symfony

The problem: Symfony toolbar shows missing messages, while the messages are... well, not missing.
It seems as if `{{ form_label(...) }}` call tries to double-translate the message. For example:

I have the following in my app/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml:

```
...
entity:
    recipe:
        title: translated title
        description: translated description
...
```

and I have the following in my FormType (AppBundle) class:

```
$builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class, ['label' => 'entity.recipe.title'])
    ->add('description', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'entity.recipe.description']);
```

and in the app/Resources/views template:

```
<div class="title_row">
{{ form_label(form.title) }}
{{ form_widget(form.title, { 
    'attr': {
        'class': 'supertitle',
        'placeholder': 'entity.recipe.title'|trans
    }}) 
}}
{{ form_errors(form.title) }}
</div>


<div class="description_row">
{{ form_label(form.description) }}
{{ form_errors(form.description) }}
{{ form_widget(form.description, { 
    'attr': {
        'class': 'metro',
        'placeholder': 'recipe.describe_your_recipe'|trans
    }}) 
}}
</div>
```

In this case, Symfony toolbar shows 2 missing messages for `translated title` and `translated description`. It is not complaining about message keys, but about already translated messages.  As if symfony tries to translate the same message twice.

If I drop the `form_label`, `form_errors` and  `form_widget` and replace them with a single `form_row`, then everything works fine.

Also, `php bin/console debug:trans` does not show these messages as missing.

I have tested this with the original `form_div_layout.html.twig` without any customizations, and it still shows these errors.

Inside that file under form_label block, I found:

```
<label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
```

which is nothing out of ordinary?

Also tried to specify translation_domain within the Type class, didn't make a difference.

Currently using Symfony 3.0, although I think I saw the same errors in 2.8.

Any ideas?

thanks
Karolis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder and title attribute values get translated automatically inside the `widget_attributes` block:

```
{%- for attrname, attrvalue in attr -%}
    {{- " " -}}
    {%- if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"
    {%- elseif attrvalue is sameas(true) -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrname }}"
    {%- elseif attrvalue is not sameas(false) -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

All you have to do is removing the redundant `trans` filter from your title and placeholder values, i.e.:

```
{{ form_widget(form.title, { 
    'attr': {
        'class': 'supertitle',
        'placeholder': 'entity.recipe.title'
    }}) 
}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem very intuitive when some attributes get magically translated and others don't? What if I want these messages untranslated?

Comment: You can overwrite the form widget if you like, or you use a translation domain which doesn't contain translations.